# Suppress scientific notation in Haxe across targets

Tags: string-formatting, haxe, scientific-notation, openfl

Is there a way to suppress scientific notation in Haxe?

For example, if I have:

```
var f:Float = 0.00007075;
var s:String = Std.string(f);
```

In targets such as html5, this outputs: 0.00007075

However, c++ targets output: 7.075e-05

Is there a way to control whether scientific notation is used for string format?

Comment: You might want to mark your answer as accepted? :)

Answer (score 2):

Credits to Hugh Sanderson of GameHaxe who answered this at a forum.

Global output mode for floats can be changed using an extern:

```
class Test
{
  @:native("__hxcpp_set_float_format") @:extern
  static function setFloatFormat(format:String):Void { }

  public static function main()
  {
    trace(0.00005);
    trace(5e20);
    setFloatFormat("%.12f");
    trace(0.00005);
    trace(5e20);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can switch to a different library to convert floats to strings which specifies the format. E.g., https://github.com/polygonal/printf/blob/master/src/de/polygonal/Printf.hx#L119

Comment: Franco Ponticelli also has a similar [thx.format](https://github.com/fponticelli/thx.format/blob/master/src/thx/format/NumberFormat.hx) at GitHub